# PL/SQL procedure: UPDATE uppercase names to initcaps, with special handling for some values

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, procedure

I need a procedure to do something like this: original name: AMSTERDAM new name: Amsterdam.
I made this procedure for it:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE NaamRoutine
is
BEGIN
  update Gemeentenew
  set gemeentenaam = lower(gemeentenaam);
  update Gemeentenew
  set gemeentenaam = initcap(gemeentenaam); 
END;
```

The problem is there are a couple of names that start like 'S GRAVENHAGE and need to be 's Gravenhage.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the special handling is necessary only for names like `'S...`, adding a simple `REPLACE` should work.  BTW, you don't need two separate `UPDATE` statements - `INITCAP` will automatically convert non-initial characters to lowercase.:

```
with v_data(name) as (
  select 'AMSTERDAM' from dual union all
  select '''S GRAVENHAGE' from dual union all
  select 'DEN HAAG' from dual union all
  select 'IJSLAND' from dual
  )
select 
  replace(nls_initcap(name, 'NLS_SORT=xDutch'), '''S', '''s') name
from v_data

Name
----
Amsterdam
's Gravenhage
Den Haag
IJsland
```

This will replace all occurrences of `'S` with `'s`. If you need to handle other cases as well, I suggest you try `REGEXP_REPLACE()`.

The function [`NLS_INITCAP`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions110.htm#SQLRF51552) helps with some globalization issues.  For example, it capitalizes both the `I` and the `J` in `IJSLAND`.  But it doesn't help with `'S` names.  I'm not sure if that is a bug with Oracle's globalization functions or if those city names are all exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

In the first place, if you want to manipulate the same field twice, nest them rather than perform them separately.

```
select initcap( lower( '''S GRAVENHAGE' )) as Resp from dual;
```

However, you don't even need to do that in this case. `initcap` will give you what you want all by itself.

Now, if you have something that starts with an 's and a space ('s xxx), then you can then run it through a regex replacement.

```
select regexp_replace( initcap( '''S GRAVENHAGE' ), '^''S ', '''s ' ) as Resp from dual;
```

Comment: It should be `'''S`, not `'S`.

Comment: Ah, so the single quote is part of the data. Easily fixed, as shown.