# initcap only for words with more than three character

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I'm trying to create a select statement applying initcap to a field, but I'd like to make uppercase only the words with more than three characters.

Please note that I can't create an external function and my question is not solved by this answer:
[Initcap skip words smaller than 4 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24210341/initcap-skip-words-smaller-than-4-characters)

because they solved using a procedure to manually check the matches.

So I'd like to use something:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(initcap(myField),"\w{1,10}\b") FROM dual
```

MyField contains something like GUNS N ROSES, and I'd like to transform into Guns n Roses

Comment: `REGEXP_REPLACE()` needs 3 arguments: the column name, the regexp, and the replacement string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute separate logic for it.

It needs statement to be broken into individual word and do `initcap` if `length` is more than 3 characters. After that combine them using `aggregate function`.

```
WITH DATAA AS
(SELECT 'GUNS N ROSES' AS STR FROM DUAL)

SELECT LISTAGG(CASE WHEN LENGTH(STRR) > 3       
                    THEN INITCAP(STRR) 
                    ELSE STRR 
               END, ' ')
       WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY LVL) AS RESULT
FROM
  (SELECT LEVEL AS LVL, 
          LOWER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(STR, '[^ ]+', 1, LEVEL)) AS STRR
     FROM DATAA
   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(STR, ' ') + 1);
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c014bab8a7988b8d28cb4c8371dff6d9)

Cheers!!

Comment: Good job, but you're missing a close paren at the end of your example.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Tejash's answer, but with some extra logic for doing CONNECT BY on multiple rows.

```
-- example data
with mytable as (select 'GUNS N ROSES' as myfield from dual
            union select 'SALPHEN AAN DEN RIJN' from dual
            union select 'KAAG EN BRAASSEM' from dual)
-- query
select listagg(CASE WHEN length(words.word) > 3 
                    THEN initcap(words.word) 
                    ELSE lower(words.word) 
               END, ' ') within group (order by words.lvl)
from 
  (select myfield, regexp_substr(myfield,'\w+', 1, level) as word, level as lvl
    from mytable
    connect by regexp_substr(myfield, '\w+', 1, level) is not null
      and PRIOR myfield = myfield
      and PRIOR SYS_GUID() is not null) words
group by words.myfield  
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the values word-by-word without splitting and re-aggregating the sentence.

**Oracle Setup**

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name( sentence ) AS
SELECT 'GUNS N ROSES' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'THIS IS A SENTENCE THAT SHOULD BE IN INITCAPS IF IT HAS MORE THAN THREE LETTERS' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'FOUR THREE TWO ONE' FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```sql
WITH replaced ( sentence, startidx, endidx ) AS (
  SELECT LOWER( sentence ),
         1,
         REGEXP_INSTR( sentence, '\W', 1 )
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT CASE
         WHEN endidx - startidx <= 3
         THEN sentence
         ELSE  SUBSTR( sentence, 1, startidx - 1 )
            || INITCAP( SUBSTR( sentence, startidx, endidx - startidx ) )
            || SUBSTR( sentence, endidx )
         END,
         endidx + 1,
         REGEXP_INSTR( sentence, '\W', endidx + 1 )
  FROM   replaced
  WHERE  endidx > 0
)
SELECT CASE
       WHEN LENGTH( sentence ) - startidx <= 3
       THEN sentence
       ELSE  SUBSTR( sentence, 1, startidx - 1 )
          || INITCAP( SUBSTR( sentence, startidx ) )
       END AS sentence
FROM   replaced
WHERE  endidx = 0
```

**Output**:

> ```
> | SENTENCE                                                                        |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------ |
> | Guns n Roses                                                                    |
> | Four Three two one                                                              |
> | This is a Sentence That Should be in Initcaps if it has More Than Three Letters |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f09a7c600e206c722b0a548afb59a5df)*